# How to dynamically change yaxis label in JQplot

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I'm using jqplot and I would like to dynamically change the label of my yaxis.

I have trying the following:

```
plot1.axes.yaxis.label = "New label";
plot1.replot();
```

Unfortunately the label of my axis is this the same as the declaration of my plot1 options.

It is posible to dynamically change the yaxis (or xaxis) label?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
plot1.axes.yaxis.labelOptions.label = "hi mom";
plot1.replot();
```

Or if you are **NOT** using the `canvasAxisLabelRenderer` you can manipulate the DOM div element directly:

```
$('.jqplot-yaxis-label').html("hi mom");
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise the difference between yaxis.label and yaxis.labelOptions! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also directly provide options in the `replot()` function, like this:

```
plot1.replot( {
    axis : {
        yaxis : {
            labelOptions: {
                label: 'hi mom'
            }
        }
    }
});
```